# $group returning empty rows when I use aggregate

Tags: python, django, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

I want **DISTINCT** rows with my query. I am getting total instead of distinct rows. I tried `$group` but that is returning empty rows

Query:

```
  pipeline = mycol.aggregate([
    { '$lookup': {'from': "theUL", 'localField': "data.rID", 'foreignField': "aR", 'as': "yo"} },
    { '$unwind': "$yo"},
    {"$unwind":"$tags"},{'$match': {'tags.tag.name':'A A', 'url': {'$regex': 'abc.com'}}},
   {'$group':{ '_id' : {'aR': "$aR"}} },
   { '$project': {"aR":1, "yo.user_email":1,   "_id":0} }
])  

for doc in pipeline:
   pprint (doc)
```

Result:

```
{ }
{ }
{ }
```

Expected Result:

```
Distinct rows
```

I am new to MongoDB. Please help

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: In your $group stage, you just define an _id without acculumator  => output only _id. In $project, 'aR' doesn't exist (but '_id.aR does!), and yo.user-email doesn't exist too (due to $group with only _id)